# vb.net Chr KeyPress function

Tags: vb.net, validation, textbox, ascii

When validating textboxes in vb.net, I usually use the .Chr or .ChrW function to define the valid ranges of ASCII values that can be entered. Today I came across something I've not had to do before, where I had to use this function in the `e.KeyChar <> Chr(156)` format, but replace the value 156 with the value for the GBP sign, or £

However, after finding out online via ASCII tables that the ASCII value is 156, I ran the code, and it wouldn't let me enter a £. What is the fix for this? Is there something I'm missing?

```
 Private Sub txtFVal_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtFVal.KeyPress

    If e.KeyChar <> Chr(156) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> Chr(46) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> Chr(44) AndAlso e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Oemcomma) _
    AndAlso (e.KeyChar < Chr(48) OrElse e.KeyChar > Chr(57)) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> Chr(8) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It is only 156 in code page 437, the legacy OEM code page that's used in consoles.  The Chr() function assumes you specify codes in the legacy Windows code page (usually 1252 in Western Europe and the Americas), makes it 163.   Lesson learned here is to as far away from this code page misery as you can, never use Chr() and always use Unicode.  Which makes it ChrW(&HA3) or the sane and readable `"£"c`

Comment: @HansPassant Okay, so, I took off `e.KeyChar <> Chr(156)` and added `AndAlso e.KeyChar = ChrW(&HA3)` to the end - Still nothing happens? No £ is displayed... Do I need the Shift key code also?

Comment: What key do you actually press?  If you set a breakpoint on the event handler, type the key and inspect e.KeyChar with the debugger then what do you see?

Comment: @HansPassant I'm pressing `Shift` + `3`. When debugging, it says `KeyChar = "£"c`

Comment: Quote: "use the sane and readable  `"£"c`"

Comment: @HansPassant : Oh, you just wrote a comment about it as I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having to lookup its ASCII number just specify the char itself by suffixing a string with `c` - which in VB.NET indicates that you've specified a char literal:

```
If e.KeyChar <> "£"c AndAlso ...
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here's a more clean `If`-statement, see if it works:

```
If Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) = False AndAlso e.KeyChar <> "£"c _
    AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ","c AndAlso e.KeyChar <> "."c _
     AndAlso e.KeyChar <> Chr(8) Then
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

Comment: Hi Vincent, this still doesn't seem to output the £ symbol into my textbox?

Comment: @David : Perhaps not all of your expressions evaluate to True? For example this doesn't seem right: `AndAlso e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Oemcomma)`. Suddenly you are checking if the char IS a comma (or whatever it results in).

Comment: Even after taking this line out (which I was using to allow the insertion of commas), it doesn't display it. Also tried changing from `AndAlso` to `OrElse`

Comment: Nevermind, for some reason it isn't accepting ANY characters anymore, so the £ isn't the issue

Comment: @David : You were currently disallowing the use of commas, you should've used the `<>` operator instead of `=`. -- What happens if you temporarily remove all you code and try checking just for `£`?

Comment: Well you have a rather messy if-statement. :)

Comment: The project seems to be a bit buggy. I rebuilt the solution several times and now the code works fine, thank you

Comment: @David : I took the liberty of making a more clean and better readable `If`-statement. Try that too if you like.